# Is there a name for the product of a matrix 'embedded' between another matrix and it transposed

Tags: naming-conventions, matrix-multiplication, quaternions

I'm looking for a name for the following, frequently recurring, product. Or better said: curious whether such a name or names exist.

"A times B times (A transposed)"

Where A and B can be matrices, but it also comes in similar forms with vectors and quaternions:

"Q times V times (Q conjugated)"

Since it's hard to look for something you don't know how to call (unless google has a mathematical  symbolical search feature that I haven't discovered yet...) I'm hoping to share in your knowledge.

Note that my interest is more of a curiosity than a quest for the one truth, since I well aware naming convention as notation conventions can differ from field to field and even person to person.

Regards,

Rouke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ABA^T` case is covered [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) (that's ["congruence transformation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_transformation)). For transformations with orthogonal matrices / unit quaternions (where `A^T` equals `A^{-1}`, and `conj(Q)` equals `Q^{-1}`), this is also equivalent to `ABA^{-1}`, which you can read about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similar_matrix).